# Direct limit, inverse limit and Spec

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, schemes, limits-colimits

**The set-up**

1. $k$ is a field
2. $T_i = \operatorname{Spec} A_i$ is an inverse system of affine $k$-schemes, where $i<j$ if $\operatorname{Spec} A_j \subset \operatorname{Spec} A_i$ (inclusion).
3. $X$ is a $k$-variety (hence locally of finite presentation).

Then, by [this porposition](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01ZB), we have

$$ \operatorname{Mor}(\varprojlim_i T_i, X) = \varinjlim_i \operatorname{Mor}(T_i, X)$$

**The confusion**

In the proof, we use the direct limit $A = \varinjlim_i A_i$ and then use it to create the inverse system $T_i$ using the fact that $\varphi : A \to B$ induces $\operatorname{Spec} \phi: \operatorname{Spec} B \to \operatorname{Spec} A$ via contraction. This should work sice the functor between rings and schemes is contravariant. However, the converse relation isn't true: [spec of inverse limit of rings is not same as direct limit of spec of rings](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/241473/).

**The question**

How can we get the direct system $(A_i, \varphi_{ij})$ from the above inverse system $(T_i, f_{ij})$? In particular, what is the meaning of this statement

$$\varprojlim_i \operatorname{Spec} A_i = \operatorname{Spec} \varinjlim_i A_i$$

**Edit**

I have realized that this was a dumb question. The scheme morphism $\operatorname{Spec} A \to \operatorname{Spec} B$ by definition gives the ring  homomorphism $B \to A$. Moreover, as commented below by  Martin Brandenburg and Zhen Lin on the linked question, spectrum commutes with filtered colimits (direct limit).

Comment: It's *really* hard to tell what you do and don't understand here and what you are asking for an explanation of.  How you get the direct system is completely trivial: a morphism $f_{ij}:\operatorname{Spec}A_j\to\operatorname{Spec} A_i$ of schemes gives you a morphism $\varphi_{ij}:A_i\to A_j$ of rings.

Comment: It's also not clear why you think https://math.stackexchange.com/a/241473/ is relevant at all.

Comment: @EricWofsey Given the inclusion morphism $f_{ij}: \operatorname{Spec} A_j \to \operatorname{Spec} A_i$ what is the defintion of the map $\varphi_{ij}: A_i \to A_j$?

Comment: @EricWofsey I linked to the other answer since I think it says that $\varinjlim_i \operatorname{Spec} A_i \neq \operatorname{Spec} \varprojlim_i A_i$, something I would have expected to hold due to contravarience.

Comment: It sounds like you are quite shaky on the basics of scheme theory.  I would suggest studying the basics more thoroughly before you try to understand a theorem like this.

Comment: The spectrum commutes not with all colimits, yes, but: we have a *filtered* colimit, and there it works.